# RestSharp, Basic Auth

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

I have a question about making an authorized call to a GET Url using RestSharp.

I have a provided basic token, which looks something like this: dGVzdG5hbWU6dGVzdHBhc3N3b3Jk.

Let's say the GET Url is: https://sometest.api.com/todos?id=1 and requires authorization.

How would I pass the above token in the above GET Url?

I tried this:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://sometest.api.com") // base address
var request = new RestRequest("todos?id=1"); // resource
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic dGVzdG5hbWU6dGVzdHBhc3N3b3Jk");

var response = client.Execute(request);
```

This does not seem to work. Do I need to add the basic token as a parameter instead, or both in the header and as parameter?

Or would I need to use the client.Authenticator on the RestClient:

```
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("testname", "testpassword");
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Best Regards

Comment: I missed a small detail, it should be:

Comment: var request = new RestRequest("todos?id=1", Method.GET); // resource, although I think it defaults to that.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information how did you conclude that it does not work? Any exception? An error message you could provide?

How did you get that token? What the expiration time of the token?

This is how I am doing it, pretty much like you, except I am using different token type:

```
var request = CreateServerRequest(_configuration.SOME_URI);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {Token}");
request.AddJsonBody(request);

var server = new RestClient(_configuration.SOME_ENDPOINT);
var serverResponse = server.Execute(request);
if (serverResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
     return new ServiceResponse<bool>(true);
}
```

Where the method CreateServerRequest contains only:

```
return new RestRequest(uri)
{
   RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
   Method = Method.POST
};
```

Hope this helps, 
Cheers and happy coding.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks, and sorry for late reply. I will see if your example works. 

The error I am getting is:
In header:
 "Server Error"
In content: 404 - File or directory not found.
 "The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had it's name changed, or is unavavilable."

I've tried with Postman and it works, by setting the Get Url, setting the query parameter and adding the token to the header.

Best Regards